# How can I know the 'long' value reached to Long.MAX_VALUE

Tags: java, android, genetic-algorithm

Below is my code, but the `if` statement doesn't work.

```
int i = 0;
while (true) {
  long l = fibonacci(i++);
  if (l < 0L && l > Long.MAX_VALUE) {
    System.out.println("over");
    break;
}
```

}

How can I know if the `long` value has reached `Long.MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: L never be greater than Long.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: `l > Long.MAX_VALUE` You should really just look at that condition for a second.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If a `long` value has exceeded the bounds for a `long`, then overflow will occur.  The next Fibonacci number will appear to be a negative number due to this overflow.  So checking for a numbers less than zero is correct.  But you don't need to check if it's greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`, because no `long` can satisfy that condition.  The `&&` was another mistake; a number can't simultaneously be less than zero and greater than that (any) positive number.

You just need:

```
if (l < 0L) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much,your answer is correct. and  "l < 0L && l > Long.MAX_VALUE",if 1< 0L return false ,this statment "l < 0L && l > Long.MAX_VALUE" return false?

Comment: @wyf Yes, your original condition would have returned `false` always, not just if it had exceeded `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I was sceptical on whether or not `l < 0L` was guaranteed to catch an overflow but it is. I did Long.MAX_VALUE + Long.MAX_VALUE and got -2, so there's no way you can overflow so far into positive numbers again. That is of course, if you do an overflow check between every addition.